# Does Google App Engine have reserved file names?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm using App Engine for a PHP 7.3 Standard application. I was just organizing a few things including some cron jobs. For those cron jobs I had named the files like this:

**cron-sample-name.php**

After a deployment I tried to run the cron job and get this in the log -

*"PHP message: PHP Warning: require(cron-sample-name.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/index.php on line 271" while reading response header from upstream"*

So, my front controller is saying it can't find the file. After trying several things and numerous deployments, I rename the file to:

**cro-sample-name.php**

Just like that, it works fine. I'm wondering if this is a bug or is there a list of reserved file names I shouldn't be using. Haven't been able to find one. Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK there's no list of reserved filenames on GAE. There are a few special filenames depending on the runtime environment, e.g. `requirements.txt` for Python or `composer.json` for PHP. Regardless, one idea that comes to my mind is that the file was being ignored due to being listed in the `.gcloudignore` and thus wasn't being uploaded. Is the name `cron-sample-name.php` the real filename you were having issues with?

Comment: Are you using the standard or flex environment? Did you change anything on your code that may affect this file?

Comment: Yes! My .gcloudignore file had "cron*" in it. I must have added that years ago and totally forgot about it. Thank you sir.